# How do I remove old files so that I keep one for every week, one for every month, etc.?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, backup

I do regular backups on my linux server but as it is now I delete all backups older than 14 days. I'd prefer if I could do it as sbackup or deja-dup. There you have the choice to keep all yesterdays backups, one backup per week, one backup per month and one backup per year.

I don't fully understand what logic I should implement to achieve something like this. Can anyone help me with pointers on how to implement this and maybe suggestion on packages that can be of help?

Comment: This is a straight out request for a script, perhaps if you could show us what you attempted then flag to re-open/migrate to another more suitable site. Thanks.

Comment: No, what I asked for was for tips on how the logic should be and tips on what components I can use.

Comment: @kev: Can you please vote to reopen now that I've rephrased my question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) which was built especially for this backup strategy.